# Using HAML, Scaml or Jade with Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, haml, pug, scaml

Is it possible to use Haml (or similar tempting languages like Scaml or Jade) in Play views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [Scalate, template engine](http://www.playframework.org/modules/scalate-0.3/home).

Comment: I don't think a 2.0-compatible plugin has yet been released. Nevertheless, http://janhelwich.wordpress.com/ has some blog posts about Scalate with Play 2.0.

Comment: There are now various 2.0 plugins: https://github.com/adetante/play2-scalate https://github.com/bartschuller/play2-scalate

Answer (score 5):

Well I am unsure if anyone had any luck on this. So let me share what I did.

I am using play 2.1.1 with scala. Integrating Play (Scala) with Jade is a pain.

If you are comfortable with haml, Jade is probably the closest to it.

The integration of play 2.* with jade isn't that great, especially if you are working with sbt. Installing scalate is a bit of an overkill as it is pretty heavy weight. I used a Java library called Jade4J which is written in Java.

You can see my solution [here](https://gist.github.com/geetchandratre/5705523) .. pretty clean and easy.

There are some plugins like play2-scalate which might help you but they get the whole scalate library which is not really required. Hope this helps. Cheers